# Why is the select() function from WinSock2.h named as such?

Tags: sockets, select, network-programming, winsock

Why is the `select()` function from `WinSock2.h` named as such? 
What is being selected?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select

Comment: Because that's what it's called in the Berkely Sockets API. You are selecting FDs that are ready for  I/O.

Comment: I see, thanks, looked into that and found these links:
1) https://csperkins.org/teaching/2010-2011/networked-systems/lab03.pdf
2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor